# Does VisualHG work with Visual Studio 2010 beta 2?

Tags: visual-studio, mercurial, visual-studio-2010, visualhg

Since I installed it on my Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 I couldn't make it work. I don't know if it is because it is incompatible or it is because I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works. I couldn't make it work on Windows 7 64-bit, but in Windows 7 32-bit it played nice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does work with MSVC 2010 beta2